# Rename a list of files in Windows CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I want to add a suffix (or prefix) to each of the filenames in a specific list.

Something like the below would work, but I don't want to capture all the .tsv files in the directory, only the ones that I specify in a list

```
forfiles /S /M *.tsv /C "cmd /c rename @file Early_@file
```

The list of files would look like the below, and I would preferably want to add "Early" to the end of the filenames as a suffix, but the beginning of the filenames would work as well:

```
("DXOpen_BuysideAnalytics_AmerEqty_SF_20180502.tsv";"DXOpen_BuysideAnalytics_AmerEqty_IM_20180502.tsv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bat
@Echo off
Set List="DXOpen_BuysideAnalytics_AmerEqty_SF_20180502.tsv";"DXOpen_BuysideAnalytics_AmerEqty_IM_20180502.tsv"
For %%I in (%List%) Do Ren %%I "%%~nI_EARLY%%~xI"
```

The `For` command iterates through elements contained in the variable `List` (where elements are separated by semicolons, commas, spaces or tabs).  At each iteration through the `For` loop, the current element is represented by the variable `%%I`.

The upper case letter `I` for a variable name is my choice, in general any letter, upper or lower case, can be used. Upper case is distinct from lower case.

The "for variable" (`%I` in this case) has optional modifiers.  See this snippet from `help for` or `for /?`:

```bat
    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
```

I use these modifiers to create the new name by inserting `_EARLY` between the original name `%%~nI` and the extension `%%~xI`

Don't get confused by the two percent signs - in a batch file they have to be doubled; on the command line use single ones.

Comment: can you explain, please ? Thx.

Comment: @SherylHohman - There are many things that could be explained. Is there something specific that is not described in the `FOR /?` help output?

Comment: my comment was *before* you edited to include explanation. many thanks.